# PHP - create a JSON object with multiple arrays

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a PHP function to create a directory tree and I cannot format the result to obtain a JSON file like this:

```
[
  {
    text: 'Parent',
    href: 'parent/',
    nodes: [
      {
        text: 'Child',
        href: 'child/',
        nodes: [
          {
            text: 'Grandchild',
            href: 'grandchild/',
          },
          {
            text: 'Grandchild',
            href: 'grandchild/',
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        text: 'Child',
        href: 'child/',
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    text: 'Parent',
    href: 'parent/',
  },
  {
    text: 'Parent',
    href: 'parent/',
  },
  {
    text: 'Parent',
    href: 'parent/',
  },
  {
    text: 'Parent',
    href: 'parent/',
  },
  {
    text: 'Parent',
    href: 'parent/',
    nodes: [
      {
        text: 'Child',
        href: 'child/',
        nodes: [
          {
            text: 'Grandchild',
            href: 'grandchild/',
          },
          {
            text: 'Grandchild',
            href: 'grandchild/',
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        text: 'Child',
        href: 'child/',
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Here my PHP function, someone can help me? Thanks

```
function scandir_rec($root)
{
    $data = [];

    if (!is_dir($root)) {
        return;
    }

    $dirs = scandir($root);

    foreach ($dirs as $dir) {

        if ($dir == '.' || $dir == '..') {
            continue;
        }

        $path = $root . '/' . $dir;  

        $data[] = ['text'=>$dir, 'link'=>urlencode($path)];

        if (is_dir($path)) {

            $data[] = ['nodes' => scandir_rec($path)]; 

        }
    }

    return json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
}

// init call
$rootDir = '/var/usr';

scandir_rec($rootDir);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

^what those guys said.

```php
<?php
function scandir_rec($root)
{
    $data = [];

    if (!is_dir($root)) {
        return;
    }

    $dirs = scandir($root);

    foreach ($dirs as $dir) {

        if ($dir == '.' || $dir == '..') {
            continue;
        }

        $path = $root . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $dir;

        if (!is_dir($path)) continue;

        $chunk = ['text' => $dir, 'link' => urlencode($path)];

        $nodes = scandir_rec($path);
        if (!empty($nodes)) $chunk['nodes'] = $nodes;

        $data[] = $chunk;
    }

    return $data;
}

$rootDir = '/var/usr';

json_encode(scandir_rec($rootDir), JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Comment: Thank for uour help. I tried your code and I get empty nodes when a folder is empty, so I modified it "if (is_dir($path) && count(scandir($path)) !== 0)" but I still get an empty node and an extra array at the end of the JSON data. I've been scratching my head for 1 hour.

Comment: `count(scandir($path))` will be 2 if directory is empty, due to `.` and `..`

Comment: Yes you are right. however I always get an empty node and an additional array at the end. I will take the code from the beginning.

Comment: always the same problem, it even adds the files. it's strange.

Comment: Thought you wanted files. Add `if (is_file($path)) continue;` under `$path = $root . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $dir;`

Comment: I did an is_dir but I prefer your solution. I'm testing

Comment: good job, the formatting is correct. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that after each recursive call, you return the sub data as a json encoded string rather than the data hierarchy.  You could change this to return the data and the caller would have to json encode the result.

Alternatively, when you do the recursive call, `json_decode()` the return value.  So change the line...

```
$data[] = ['nodes' => scandir_rec($path)];
```

to

```
$data[] = ['nodes' => json_decode(scandir_rec($path), true)];
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in answer before, your are json encoding the result of each return value of `scandir_rec`, with the final encoded string ending up quite messy.

Another undesirable result occurs because of the line `$data[] = ['nodes' => scandir_rec($path)];`. Resulting in a data structure that does not resemble the structure of the JSON file you presented, but instead considers the entire result as an array instead of an object. I believe you might want to consider doing something like this:

```php
function scandir_rec($root)
{
    if (!is_dir($root)) {
        return [];
    }

    $data = [];
    $data['text'] = $root;
    $data['href'] = urlencode($root);
    $nodes = [];

    $dirs = scandir($root);
    foreach ($dirs as $dir) {
        if ($dir === '.' || $dir === '..') {
            continue;
        }
        $path = $root . '/' . $dir;
        if (is_dir($path)) {
            $nodes[] = scandir_rec($path);
        }
    }
    if (false === empty($nodes)) {
        $data['nodes'] = $nodes;
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Which results in a matching structure of your example.

Edit:

To get the result that you want, you could then do something like:

```php
$directory = __DIR__;
$result = scandir_rec($directory);
$data = json_encode($data);
```

Comment: In your example, `nodes` defaults to an empty array.

Comment: No, I meant the given JSON example does not feature the key `nodes` when the node has no children.

Comment: Thank for your help.  I get an empty node and an extra array at the end of the JSON data.